# for loop prevents context switch

Tags: java

The subsequent simple Java program behaves quite strange. After starting the two threads, both of them do their work first. After same time it seems that the first thread is not preempted anymore, because the second thread stops to print out trace messages. After the first thread finishes, the second thread resumes its work.

The program behaves as expected, when the second version of the for loop – `i` is incremented at the beginning of the loop – is used.
I observe this behavior when I execute the program under Windows (Windows 10) and Linux (Ubuntu). I use a Java 8 compiler and a Java 8 runtime.

```
package test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class NoContextSwitch {

  private static volatile boolean stopT2 = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.printf("%s (%s): starting calculation", LocalTime.now(),
                        Thread.currentThread().getName());    
      long sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {   // version 1 of loop
      // for (int i = 0; i++ < 1000000; ) { // version 2 of loop
        for (int j = 0; j < 300000; j++)
          sum += 1;
      }      
      System.out.printf("%s (%s): finished calculation: sum=%d%n",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), LocalTime.now(), sum);    
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s (%s): i=%d%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), 
                          LocalTime.now(), i);
        if (stopT2)
          return;
      }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    stopT2 = true;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
...
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25362
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25363
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25364
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25365
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25366
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25367
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25368
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25369
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25370
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25371
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25372
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25373
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25374
Thread-1 (13:24:23.617): i=25375 // Thread-1 gets no time slice for 6 seconds
Thread-1 (13:24:29.646): i=25376
Thread-0 (13:24:29.646): finished calculation: sum=300000000000
Thread-1 (13:24:29.646): i=25377
```

### EDIT: Summary of program's behavior

After doing some further experiments, my view of the program's behavior is the following:

- At the beginning (until around 80000 passes through the outer loop) both threads are executed concurrently.
- Then something happens that causes the runtime to assign the CPU to the first thread exclusively. As long as this thread is executed no other thread gets scheduled (even not the main thread). The reason for this change in the program’s behavior might be that the hotspot compiler becomes active (see the comprehensive answer from *lorenzo* below).
- When the first thread finishes, all other threads get control again.
- Changing thread priority has no effect.
- If one inserts `Thread.sleep(0)`, `Thread.yield()`, or a print statement into the loop of the first thread the program behaves as expected (all threads get its share from the CPU time). Even accessing a volatile variable is sufficient for that.

Comment: What is the question? You could reduce the chance of this happening by setting stopT2 to true before printing out that you finished calculation and put the check for it immediately above not under the other output.

Comment: Could you please explain what you expect (or don't expect) your program to do? What is the problem?

Comment: I expect that the program behaves the same irrespective of whether I use version 1 or version 2 of the loop. I think its really quite strange that the runtime ignores thread 2 for about 6 seconds. I detected this problem in a UI application. When I do a background calculation like the one in Thread 1 the UI gets completely frozen.

Comment: does `version 1` *always* lead to `Thread-1` starvation? does `Thread-1` starvation occur *only* with `version 1`?

Comment: did you try changing thread priority?

Comment: Yes, the behavior is reproducable. The delay always happens at the same point in time. Setting thread priority to a higher value changes nothing in the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I though it was the GC kicking in even if there was not a huge amount of allocations going on.
So I run the program in this way:

```
java -verbose:gc test.NoContextSwitch
```

and there is, in fact, GC activity right before the long pause, but running it with more heap:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -verbose:gc test.NoContextSwitch
```

didn't make the delay go away.

So my second guess was the HotSpot optimizer. During normal program execution the code is profiled and when the optimizer detects an "hotspot" section of code this is optimized on the fly. Well, almost on the fly, it takes a little time.
This is the command line to check for this:

```
java -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+CITime test.NoContextSwitch
```

(see [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-2-flag-categories-and-jit-compiler-diagnostics/) for details) and so you can see the HotSpot doing its job:

```
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier::printString (105 bytes)   made not entrant
   8507  298 %     4       test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0 @ -2 (98 bytes)   made not entrant
```

I'm not able to tell you the exact kind of optimization performed, but in general anonymous classes, lambdas and the like are slower than standard code and are a common target for optimization (at least this was true some time ago...). Honestly, it took *a lot* of time for such a small class!

Out of curiosity, I tried to extract the two Thread subclasses to separate top-level classes and I got the same result.

As a side note: my very first idea was to add a Thread.yield in the worker thread to see if it made any difference. When you have a very tight loop like that it's something to consider. If and what effect that command will have on a modern JVM doing its thing it's something to evaluate/measure on each case.

## How and why the number of iterations affects the behaviour

I made a few test with different numbers in the external iteration of the worker thread:

0.1mil

```
Thread-1 (17:30:38.704): i=12936
Thread-1 (17:30:38.704   1856  281 %     4       test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0 @ -2 (98 bytes)   made not entrant
): i=12937
Thread-1 (17:30:39.534): i=12938
Thread-0 (17:30:39.533): finished calculation: sum=   1856  572       4       java.lang.Long::getChars (221 bytes)   made not entrant
30000000000
Thread-1 (17:30:39.534): i=12939
   1857  571       4       java.util.Formatter::parse (151 bytes)   made not entrant
```

0.5mil

```
Thread-1 (17:13:02.380): i=30139
Thread-1 (17:13:02.380): i=30140
Thread-1   4215  299 %     4       ( test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0 @ -2 (98 bytes)   made not entrant
17:13:05.687): i=30141
Thread-1 (17:13:05.687): i=30142
Thread-1 (17:13:05.687): i=30143
```

1mil (original value)

```
Thread-1 (17:20:47.435): i=30010
Thread-1 (17:20:47.435): i=30011
Thread-1 (17:20:55.851): i=30012
Thread-1 (17:20:55.851): i=   9324 30013 286 
%     4      Thread-1 test.NoContextSwitch:: (lambda$main$017:20:55.851 @ -2): i= (98 bytes)   made not entrant30014
Thread-1 (17:20:55.851): i=30015
```

2mil

```
Thread-1 (17:20:03.778): i=25926
Thread-1 (17:20:03.778): i=   1011  486   !   3       java.util.Formatter::format (271 bytes)   made not entrant
25927
Thread-1 (  24471  565       4       java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier::print (243 bytes)   made not entrant
  24471  288 %     4       test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0 @ -2 (98 bytes)   made not entrant
17:20:27.250): i=25928
Thread-0 (  24471  577       4       java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier::printString (105 bytes)   made not entrant
17:20:27.250): finished calculation: sum=  24472  603       4       java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier::print (463 bytes)   made not entrant
600000000000
Thread-1 (17:20:27.250): i=25929
Thread-1 (17:20:27.250): i=25930
Thread-1 (17:20:27.251): i=25931
  24472  581       4       java.util.Formatter::parse (151 bytes)   made not entrant
```

3mil

```
Thread-1 (17:19:10.247): i=12161
Thread-1 (17:19:40.630): i=12162
Thread-1  31405  ( 594 17:19:40.630      ): i=3      12163 java.lang.ClassLoader::
checkName (43 bytes)
Thread-1 (17:19:40.630  31405 ): i= 293 12164%     
4       test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0Thread-1 @ -2 ( (98 bytes)17:19:40.630   made not entrant): i=
12165
Thread-1 (17:19:40.630): i=12166
Thread-1 (17:19:40.630): i=12167
Thread-0 (17:19:40.630): finished calculation: sum=  31405  584       4       java.lang.Long::getChars (221 bytes)   made not entrant
900000000000
Thread-1 (17:19:40.630): i=12168
  31405  585       4       java.util.Formatter::parse (151 bytes)   made not entrant
```

4mil

```
Thread-1 (17:16:56.893): i=11209
Thread-1  40277  284  (%     4      17:17:36.150 test.NoContextSwitch::): i=lambda$main$0 @ -2 (98 bytes)   made not entrant11210

Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11211
Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11212
Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11213
Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11214
Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11215
Thread-0 (17:17:36.150): finished calculation: sum=  40278  585       4       java.lang.Long::getChars (221 bytes)   made not entrant
1200000000000
Thread-1 (17:17:36.150): i=11216
  40278  584       4       java.util.Formatter::parse (151 bytes)   made not entrant
Done  40278  456       3       java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier::printString (105 bytes)   made not entrant
  40278  601       4       java.io.PrintStream::printf (7 bytes)
```

So yes, the pause duration "depends" on the number of iterations. I can speculate a few things:

- with higher numbers, giving a very long delay, the program terminates as soon as the big pause is over (look for the "finished calculation" string in the output above). My gut feeling is that the worker thread is slowing the optimizer for the whole big optimization step and this makes the pause longer. With a 1mil value the optimizer kicks in and starts its work, but in the mean time the worker thread ends and the optimizer concludes it's work faster.
  This is partially reflected in the data: the "big pause", after 1mil, gets close to 20/30 seconds and somehow stabilize. Around 1/2mil I think we have the watershed.
  This would mean that the optimizer is blocking the "printer thread" while the other thread is still running. Maybe because it's optimizing this lambda only (lambda$main$1 vs lambda$main$0).
- with a short number, the big optimization steps are not triggered, so there are only small pauses. In other words we may not be looking at the same optimization or we may have a milder version of the same.
  For example, the "test.NoContextSwitch::lambda$main$0" optimization line compare multiple times.
- finally, changing the loop "structure" may change how the optimizer sees it.

Notice that the "printer thread" numbers are not a good reference and they tricked me a few times, as they are completely independent of anything else (running the same code multiple times will place the big pause at different "places").

(*) I made a couple of experiments writing to a file rather than to console but didn't got much.

Comment: The fact that suppressing JIT compilation when running the program (by using the command line option `-Djava.compiler=NONE`) supports your assumption that the hotspot compiler is causing the strange behavior. But on the other hand I also observed that the duration of the pause is dependent on the number of iterations in the first thread. Shouldn't the hotspot compilation take a fixed amount of time?

Comment: @JoeSchleiptner I updated my answer with my best guess